# Check if date between date range in excel where there are multiple date ranges in a list and output corresponding range label

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

How can I check if an `input_date` falls between two dates (a date range) in excel, where the date range exists in a list of date ranges?

So I need to check if input_date falls between **any** date range, and then if it does, return the value of the date ranged it matched with. See the below table for an example.

| Month | Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Month 1 | 1/1/2022 | 1/31/2022 |
| Month 2 | 2/1/2022 | 2/27/2022 |
| Month 3 | 3/1/2022 | 3/31/2022 |

Input vs Expected Result

| input_date | Expected Result = Month |
| --- | --- |
| 1/25/2022 | Month 1 |
| 2/3/2022 | Month 2 |

I've tried using `=IF(AND(A2>StartDate,A2<EndDate),TRUE, FALSE)` but how can I check A2 against all date ranges in a list, and output the corresponding Month value? Is the best way really just nesting if statements for a fixed number of ranges? Any dynamic approach?

Comment: How can I tweak this to account for the first column being any value not in the "mmm" format? For example, what if I labeled it Month 1, Month 2, etc.. how do I get the value "Month 1"?

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya - I've edited the question to account for the month column as being any value, outside the regular date format. How can I return the value "month 1"?

Comment: This does not work for any value in the month column. I am trying to make this dynamic. What if "month 1" said "abcdefg", and month 2 said "gasdgsg", I need to return "abcdefg" if the input_date fell within that range.

Comment: See I have edited the solution again in answers, `XLOOKUP()` should work then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try using the either of formulas like shown below,

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

---

• Formula used in cell `B7`

```
=XLOOKUP(1,(A7>=$B$2:$B$4)*(A7<=$C$2:$C$4),$A$2:$A$4,"")
```

---

If one do not have access to `XLOOKUP()` then `INDEX()` & `MATCH()` can also be used,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `C7`

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$4,MATCH(1,(A7>=$B$2:$B$4)*(A7<=$C$2:$C$4),0))
```

Comment: This answers the question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you just require the text output of the month the input date is referring to then can you not just:

```
=TEXT(A2,"mmmm")
```

Or do you have a need for something outside of your example?

Comment: I've edited the question to account for the month column as being any value, outside the regular date format. How can I return the value "month 1"?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `FILTER` function to return the appropriate item from the "*Month*" column

If  your Date Ranges are in a table named `dateRange` & the Input_Date`is in`G2`:

```
=FILTER(dateRange[Month],(G2>=dateRange[Start Date]) * (G2<=dateRange[End Date]))
```

[image]